# Would it be possible to regulate proper phosphorylation so the UPR wouldn't initiate a reactionary cell death in important cells?

Tags: biochemistry, phosphorylation

In studying the correlation of folded versus unfolded proteins and their impact on neuro-degeneration, it looks like improper phosphorylation in the chaperones (at least, in part) causes the mis-folding of proteins? If so, would it be possible to regulate proper phosphorylation so the UPR wouldn't initiate a reactionary cell death in important cells?

Comment: I think it is lot more complicated. Because amyloid and prion develop intercellular space, while chaperones are expressing inside of cells.

Comment: Please define UPR.

Comment: UPR: Unfolded Protein Response.